# Socket.io rooms is not getting message

Tags: express, websocket, socket.io

I have two file in a nodejs- express application

`first.pug`

```
var socket = io.connect('//'+document.location.hostname+':'+document.location.port, {
  query: {
    token: "XXXXXX"
    }
});    

socket.on('connect', (s) => {
    console.log('connected!');
      socket.emit('join123', 'room1');
});
```

`second.pug`

```
var socket = io.connect('//'+document.location.hostname+':'+document.location.port, {
  query: {
    token: "XXXXXX"
    }
});    
socket.on('join123', function (data) {
  console.log("join.group========================"+data);
});
```

Nodejs Server side

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.join('join123');
});
```

I dont see any message in `second.pug` when a message is pulished from `first.pug`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket.io connection made by `second.pug` never receives a message because your server never sends it a message.

Here's what `first.pug` does:

1. It creates a socket.io connection to your server.
2. When that connection succeeds, it sends a `join123` message to that server.

Here's what your socket.io server does:

1. It listens for connecting clients.
2. When a client connects, it puts that client into the `join123` room.
3. No messages are sent out to any of the connected clients.

Note: there is no listener on the server for the `join123` message that the client sent so likely something is wrong there.

Here's what `second.pug` does:

1. It create a socket.io connection to your server.
2. It listens for a `join123` message to be sent to it.

But, nothing ever sends a `join123` message to second.pug, so second.pug never receives that message.  `first.pug` sends a `join123` message to your server, but the server never sends that to anyone else.  The act of doing `socket.join('join123')` does not cause any messages to be sent.  It just adds the socket to a room by that name.  If you want the `second.pug` to get a `join123` message, you would have to write code on your server that actually sends that message either to all connections or somehow just to the `second.pug` connection.

Comment: @ManishKumar - I don't know what your code is supposed to do so not sure what to suggest.

Comment: two deliver the message of  `first.pug` to `second.pug` what i will have to do on server side. ? assume that only this many code i have related to send receive msge

Comment: @ManishKumar - On your server, you would need to listen for the message that first.pug sends to it and then when you receive that message, send a message to the socket for second.pug (if second.pug is open at the same time as first.pug).

Comment: `  socket.join('join123', () => {
    io.to('join123').emit('join123','a new user has joined the room');
  });  
  socket.on('join123', (id, msg) => {
    socket.to(id).emit('join123', "msg1");
  });  ` on server side worked